# Electron - ipcRenderer not working in Async Class

Tags: electron, ipc

i have a class with a Constructor and Async functions.
I have done `module.exports` so that i could call my Class from my `GUI.js` file and in my `GUI.js` file, i have required that class, and everything works fine.

But inside my class, im trying to do this `ipcRenderer.send('message', 'Hello');`

And im getting this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined`

is it possible to remote the ipcRenderer in my GUI.js?

Thanks.

i have required the module in my main file, and in my renderer file it sends `ipcRenderer.send('startMyClass');`

And in my Main file: `ipcMain.on('startMyClass', (event, args) => {
const client = new myClass();
client.Start();
})`

This is my class/index.js file that is being required in my main file.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this._jar = request.jar();
    this._request = request.defaults({ jar: this._jar });
  }

  async Start() {

   await this.Test();


  };

  async Test() {
    ipcRenderer.send('myMessage', 'Hello');
   }

}


module.exports = myClass;
```

EDIT:
If i dont require it, and have the whole class in my main file, i can do event.sender.send('myMSG', 'hello');

But i want to do it in my class, that's NOT in the same file as my main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending message from Main to Renderer should be done by sending to a *specific* `webContents`. That's why `event.sender.send('myMSG', 'hello')` works, while [`ipcRenderer.send`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-arg1-arg2-) not. The latter sends *from* Renderer *to* Main as stated in docs (and also, cannot be accessed from Main process as your Error told you it's undefined).

As explainded in `ipcMain`'s [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main#sending-messages) you should access the `webContents` you want to send to and call `send` on that.

So to correct your code you can

- Pass a reference to the main window to `myClass` and call `send` on that

  ```js
  class myClass {
    constructor(args) {
      // ...
      this.mainWindow = args.win
    }
    // ...
    async Test() {
      this.mainWindow.webContents.send('myMessage', 'Hello');
    }
  }
  ```
- Or `send` to the actually focused window ([`BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowgetfocusedwindow)) if that fits your needs

  ```js
  class myClass {
    // ...
    async Test() {
      BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.send('myMessage', 'Hello');
    }
  }
  ```