# Electron - ipcRenderer error: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

Tags: electron, ipc

i have a class with a Constructor and Async functions. I have done module.exports so that i could call my Class from my GUI.js file and in my GUI.js file, i have required that class, and everything works fine.

But inside my class, im trying to do this ipcRenderer.send('message', 'Hello');

And im getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined

is it possible to remote the ipcRenderer in my GUI.js?

Thanks.

i have required the module in my main file, and in my renderer file it sends `ipcRenderer.send('startMyClass');`

And in my Main file:

```
ipcMain.on('startMyClass', (event, args) => { const client = new myClass(); client.Start(); })
```

This is my class/index.js file that is being required in my main file.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

class myClass {
  constructor() {
    this._jar = request.jar();
    this._request = request.defaults({ jar: this._jar });
  }

  async Start() {

   await this.Test();


  };

  async Test() {
    ipcRenderer.send('myMessage', 'Hello');
   }

}


module.exports = myClass;
```

EDIT: If i dont require it, and have the whole class in my main file, i can do event.sender.send('myMSG', 'hello');

But i want to do it in my class, that's NOT in the same file as my main.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Electron - ipcRenderer not working in Async Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52814192/electron-ipcrenderer-not-working-in-async-class)

Comment: Don't open the same question twice (also, see the answer on the dupe)

Answer (score 0):

Write the class as below:

```
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    if ((<any>window).require) {
      try { ipc = (<any>window).require('electron').ipcRenderer; } catch (e) { throw e; }
    }
    else { console.warn('App not running inside Electron!'); }

    this._jar = request.jar();
    this._request = request.defaults({ jar: this._jar });
  }
}
```